# Match housenumbers on buildings (special case of point-in-polygon-test)

Tags: openstreetmap, c++, point-in-polygon, spatial-index

#### Task with example

I'm working with geodata (country-size) from openstreetmap. Buildings are often polygons without housenumbers and a single point with the housenumber is placed within the polygon of the building. Buildings may have multiple housenumbers.

I want to match the housenumbers to the polygons of the buildings.
[image: Example]

#### Simple solution

Foreach housenumber perform a point-in-polygon-test with each building-polygon.

#### Problem

Way too slow for about 50,000,000 buildings and 10,000,000 address-points.

#### Idea

Build and index for the building-polygons to accelerate the search for the surrounding polygon for each housenumber-point.

#### Question

What index or strategy would you recommend for this polygon-structure? The polygons never overlap and the area is sparsly covered.

---

*This is a duplicate from stackoverflow.com. It was recommended to post the question here.*

Comment: You have the data in Postgres?

Comment: No, I have the data in memory. I'm programming in C++.

Comment: Perhaps you could add the tag. Not very clear from question. Trivial to do with postgres/postgis (and also what osm is natively stored in) which is why I asked.

Comment: An rtree seems appropriate for this.  [Boost has a C++ implementation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree.html)

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/26650308/820534

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in my mapping software. I am not sure if this is helpful, so forgive me if it doesn't address your actual difficulty, but what I do when searching for addresses is a form of lazy evaluation. I find all the building polygons and address points near a desired street **after** searching for the street, so there will only be a few hundred, then match up points with polygons.